# Relationship query: A company has many employees

Tags: entity-relationship

Lets say a relationship is described as:

> A company has many employees
>
> A company has many departments
>
> A department has many employees

So, something like this;

> Company -<< Departments >>- Employees

If department table has a basic structure of:

```
// Pseduocode
company_id // Foreign key
department_id // Primary key
[employees] // Array or collection of employees
```

If we go back to this phrase;

> A Company has many employees

Does this mean that the employee table needs or requires a reference for the company_id too?

So, `Employee` would be:

```
employee_id
company_id  //  I'm not sure if this is requried or not
department_id
```

I'm intending to hopefully abstract this data into a `contracts` table in case of employees are freelancers/contracters, etc or have multiple employees.

But for now..

**My question is:**

Does my employee table require a reference to the `company` table, or is the company reference implied via the `department` table?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is implied through the `department`, so you don't conceptually  need it. Adding it, would be an example of denormalisation, and would allow inconsistencies to crop up. For example, you might have `company_1` with `department_1` and `company_2`. Now `employee_1` might be linked to `department_1` but `company_2`, because of some flaw/bug in the application code. There's no way to express this constraint as a SQL schema, so you'd have to go with more complicated stuff such as triggers, or application code checks etc.

However, sometimes you only need info about companies and employees, but not about departments. If it's really performance critical, doing the extra join with departments in order to find the company for an employee or the employees for a company might not cut it, so you'll just have to live with the denormalisation.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to do a composite foreign key constraint so that employee (department_id, company_id) references department (department_id, company_id).

Answer (score 2):

Question is: do you need a straight connection between Company and Employee? If you do, add it, if not then yes, the connection is implied through Department.

EDIT:

Technically, your Department table does not need a list of Employees. Each row of Employee table has a reference ID to Department, that's enough.

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) out for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to link Company with Employee. The relation between Departement and Company already do the job. You may need it only if there are existing particular cases requiring this relationship.